# Can I somehow put numbers to my listview in order to give different lists depending on what the user "clicks"?

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin

Just wondering If there is a way you can name your listview and seperate it by number.

So what I was thinking is there a way I could do it something like this:

```
void Clickthis1 (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
var thePage = new StartPage();

thePage.TheCategoryName ("Info1", StartPage.ourPitems[0]); //our  listview

Navigation.PushAsync (thePage);
}


void Clickthis2 (object sender, EventArgs args)
{
var thePage = new StartPage();

thePage.TheCategoryName ("Info2", StartPage.ourPitems[1]) //listview with a diff number?
 Navigation.PushAsync (thePage);
```

and the page where my list is;

```
public static List<createSomething> ourPitems = new List<createSomething>(string theCategoryName);

    public StartPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }


protected override void OnAppearing(){
getItems (); }

async void getItems () 
{
var getItems = await parseAPI.myInfo (Application.Current.Properties 
["sessionToken"].ToString ());
EmployeeList.ItemsSource = null;



ourPitems = new List<createSomething> (/* something in here then? */);

foreach (var currentItem in getItems["results"]) 
{
ourPitems.Add (new createSomething ()


{

ourUsername = currentItem ["YourName"].ToString (),
});}

EmployeeList.ItemsSource = ourPitems;

}

public class createSomething
{
public string ourUsername {get; set;}
}
```

so this obviously does not work but do I have the correct "idea" on how I should execute this?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if i get it, You have two buttons, and you want if the user click one button appears the list 1 and with the second button the list 2
If this is what you want, you can do this:

1-You should have the two lists:
List MyList1 = new List MyList1();
List MyList2 = new List MyList1();

2-And in the click button, change the item source of the ListView:

void OnClickButton1 (object sender, EventArgs args)
{

EmployeeList.ItemsSource = MyList1;
}

void OnClickButton2 (object sender, EventArgs args)
{

EmployeeList.ItemsSource = MyList2;
}